# How to program button list with 3 different texts in each

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to make a code to make buttons with 3 different texts in each.

Like so:

```
Text|Text
Text|
_________
Text|Text
Text|
_________
Text|Text
Text|

https://imgshare.io/image/wHXHd

The vertical lines are joined which means there are three sections to a button. How should I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of many ways you can do it :

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        for (int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
            LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.addView(ll1, lp);

            LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);
            lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll1.addView(ll2, lp);

            Button btn1 = new Button(this);
            btn1.setText("1");
            ll2.addView(btn1, lp);

            Button btn2 = new Button(this);
            btn2.setText("2");
            ll2.addView(btn2, lp);

            Button btn3 = new Button(this);
            btn3.setText("3");
            lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            ll1.addView(btn3, lp);
        }

    }
```

**Screenshot**
[image: screenshot]

You'll have to change it to fit your needs.

Good luck and let me know if you need help.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @JafferAlfahdawi You're welcome, don't forget to accept my solution if it helped you ;)